# Merge two YAMLs with custom merge logic in C#

Tags: c#, merge, yaml

There are 2 yaml files that need to be merged:

```
metadata:
  name: TestAlert
  description: "TestDescription"
triggers:
  async_triage:
    workflow:
      - and:
          - check_link_signal:
              args:
                device_name: "abc"
                if_name: "def"
```

Second one:

```
triggers:
  async_triage:
    workflow:
      - and:
          - check_link_signal:
              args:
                device_name: "abc_2"
                if_name: "def_2"
```

The final output needs to look like:

```
metadata:
  name: TestAlert
  description: "TestDescription"
triggers:
  async_triage:
    workflow:
      - and:
          - check_link_signal:
              args:
                device_name: "abc"
                if_name: "def"
                device_name_public: "abc_2"
                if_name_public: "def_2"
```

I tried converting the yamls to a dictionary and then recursively merging. But I am unable to apply the custom merge logic to merge the two dictionaries. Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks!

PS - The above are just examples. Essentially, we want to apply this merge logic to the fields under "args" and they can be anywhere in the file.